# Technology to use for understanding unstructured document

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, text-mining

I've multiple unstructured documents (PDFs and HTMLs). These unstructured documents have a predictable pattern. And there are 'n' instances of these patterns.

I need to write a program to extract information from these documents. The program should be in such a way that once it is trained for a particular pattern, it should be automatically pick the data points from other documents of same pattern.

Which technology to use for writing this program? Any help on specific algorithm will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your description is very ambiguous. Could you give an example of your documents?

Answer (score 0):

For such this unstructured data, you need to turn it to structured data. Try looking at Bag Of Words model and TF-IDF weighting
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Then try looking at one framework like Scikit Learn and it's application in text mining: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html